# Oracle: inserting BLOB using insert

Tags: oracle, blob

If I execute command:

```
SELECT hextoraw ('5B4F') FROM DUAL
```

or

```
INSERT INTO t_table (blobField) VALUES(TO_BLOB(hextoraw ('5B4F')))
```

Could it result differently depending on the underlying system (big-endian, little-endian)?